# Loading packages in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

There are a couple of packages that I want to use in all my chunks, but I'm not sure what a smart way to do this would be. I'm working in a .Rmd file. I've tried 
doing something like this:

````
```{r packages}
library("magrittr")
library("dplyr")
```
```{r data, cache=TRUE, dependson="packages" }
tab_str <- "name,id
Mike,1
Susan,2"
tab <- read.csv(text = morfo_str)
```
```{r name, dependson="data"}
tab %>% select(name)
```
````

But then knitr doesn't put the chunk "data" into the cache. Is there a way
to get knitr to cache packages, or somehow make a list of packages that are loaded in all chunks?

Comment: Sorry, can't get ``` to show up.

Answer (score 2):

When I knit your code I see:

```
Warning message:
code chunks must not depend on the uncached chunk "packages"
```

and adding `cache=TRUE` to the  `packages` chunk fixes this.

Did you not see that warning message?

Comment: The problem is the next time you run the code with "cache=TRUE", you can't use the packages in the other chucks.

Comment: Probably best to not depend on the chunk that loads the packages and not to cache it either. I can't really see why changing a chunk with a `library` call in it should invalidate a cached chunk, unless you are flipping between two packages with the same functionality. Also every time I've tried caching in knitr I've eventually given up :)